# I am not sure how antecedents and plurals work. when you are talking about "criticisms"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, pronouns, antecedents

> I am very open to any constructive criticisms, as they make you better.

Is it okay if I say criticisms and they in one sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"Criticism" can be either countable or uncountable, meaning the 'singular' form can refer to just one point of criticism, many points from the same source, or from more than one source.

You *can* use the countable 'criticisms', but more often than not it is used in the singular, non-countable form, and you would refer to it collectively in the singular. So, your example sentence should be:

> I am very open to any constructive **criticism**, as **it makes** you better.

Comment: Thanks very much! 

Could I have used criticisms in the sentence or that would have been grammatically incorrect?